# Rails - Restart designing the whole model from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Rails newbie, so please bear with me.

I've screwed up my migrations, tables and the model itself as a whole, pretty badly.

However, I have no data in there, and I want to completely start designing my whole model from scratch, without having to deal with the migrations that currently exist.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is just a local development project and you've not shared the code with anybody or deployed it anywhere ... you can simply delete the migration files, run `rake db:reset` and start again with a new migration file.

If the above isn't true, and you have shared the code or deployed it somewhere, you're safer creating reverse migrations to *undo* the original ones, migrate them and then create new ones as required.